# CSS - word-break changes element position

Tags: html, css, layout, word-break

Im trying to do a little dashboard for some webservices i wrote, but whenever text within a widget breaks, the widget changes its position.

CSS looks like this:

```
#container {
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.widget {
   background-color: firebrick;
   margin: 1px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   word-break: break-all;
 }
```

I reproduced that problem in a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vbb6fhz0/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align the box, then use float for better result. word-break has nothing to do with alignment.

But in your case, just `vertical-align: middle` solved the alignment issue

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.widget {
  background-color: firebrick;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="widget">
        <p>1dawdawdaegsergsergsrsrgrsddadawdadawdwdwbf</p>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        2wdadawdad
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        3wadawdwdawda
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        4dawdawdaw
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing bad with work-break you should try float

```
.widget{float:left;}
```

Comment: edit: that helped with the strange positioning, but I wanted the widgets to be centered in the div. float:left; overrides the centering.